# Hiding Inline Attachments from Recipient

Tags: c#, mailmessage

I'm trying to generate a MailMessage and set various attachments to it. The inline attachments always appear to the recipient as either jpeg, png, or other image files if I add them as an Attachment type. The code I used for this approach:

```
var mailMessage = new MailMessage();
// Set To, From, Body, Subject, etc.

foreach(var att in self.Attachments) {
    byte[] content = att.GetBytes();
    var attachment = new Attachment(new MemoryStream(content), att.Name);
    if(att.IsInline){
        attachment.ContentId = att.Name;
        attachment.ContentDisposition.Inline = true;
        attachment.ContentDisposition.DispositionType = DispositionTypeNames.Inline;
    }
    mailMessage.Attachments.Add(attachment)
}

var view = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(mailMessage.Body, Encoding.UTF8, MediaTypeNames.Text.Html);
mailMessage.AlternateViews.Add(view);
```

If I add them as a LinkedResource then they show up as dat files in the attachment section. Code:

```
var mailMessage = new MailMessage();
// Set To, From, Body, Subject, etc.

var view = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(mailMessage.Body, Encoding.UTF8, MediaTypeNames.Text.Html);
foreach(var att in self.Attachments) {
    byte[] content = att.GetBytes();
    if(att.IsInline) {
        var inline = new LinkedResource(new MemoryStream(content), att.ContentType);
        inline.ContentId = att.Name;
        view.LinkedResources.Add(inline);
    }
    else {
        mailMessage.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(new MemoryStream(content),
        att.Name));
    }
}

mailMessage.AlternateViews.Add(view);
```

Both approaches generate the correct email and inject the inline attachments into the body of the email. Neither show the inline attachments in the attachment section while previewing the email in outlook. Both show the inline attachments when receiving the email in outlook. I have made sure that the outlook settings are as follows in the mail section of Outlook Options: "Compose message in this format: HTML" and "When sending  messages in Rich Text format to Internet recipients: Convert to HTML format".

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated as the additional attachments are creating confusion to the end users.

Comment: I once did this and there was a way. I don't recall what it was. I found out by setting every option to every possible value in all combinations. I then sent those dozens of mails to my Outlook and picked the best settings combination. It is doable.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled on this question having had the same problem, and for me the solution was to add the type of the attachment.

Change this

```
var inline = new LinkedResource("logo.png");
```

To this

```
var inline = new LinkedResource("logo.png", "image/png");
```

**It looks as if you are already doing this**, but perhaps that wasn't working as intended?

Thanks to this page for providing the answer:
https://www.codeproject.com/articles/31897/embed-an-image-in-email-using-asp-net